# Convert empty strings of a list to float

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings like this:

```
grades = [['2.0', '3.67', '3.67', '2.33', '3.67', '2.0', '3.67', '2.33', '3.0', '2.33', '', '3.67', '2.33', '2.67', '3.0', '2.0', '4.0', '3.33', '4.0'],[...]]
```

and it contains grades but it also has empty items. When I convert it to float it deletes those empty.

What I do is the following:

```
def try_convert(val):
    try:
        return float(val)
    except ValueError as TypeError:
        pass

floatGrades = [[float(z) for z in (try_convert(j) for j in i) if z] for i in grades]
```

Is there a way of turning the empty strings like this into 0?or None?

Comment: `[float(z) if z else None for z in (try_convert(j) for j in i)]` or `[float(z) if z else float(0) for z in (try_convert(j) for j in i)]`

Comment: It's dropping them because of the `if z`. What's the intent with that?

Comment: Even better, `floatGrades = [[try_convert(z) for z in i] for i in grades]`.  You should also change `pass` to `return None`; `None` is already being implicitly returned, so better to be explicit.

Comment: @jmunsch it gives me this error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' (for the return float(val)) when I do the: [float(z) if z else float(0) for z in (try_convert(j) for j in i)]. Is there another way? Because if I put it None then I cannot do some calculations it gives me error so 0 is better

Comment: @0x5453 what if I want it to be 0 and not None?

Comment: Then `return 0`. He's pointing out that in proper Python, *every* path should explicitly return a value if *any* path returns a value.

Comment: aa okay okay! Thank you @Carcigenicate I am new to all these so I did not get it right. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using the function only to check if is possible or not. With that you would be able to make the function more generic; for general use:

```
grades = [['2.0', '3.67', '3.67', '2.33', '3.67', '2.0', '3.67', '2.33', '3.0', '2.33', '', '3.67', '2.33', '2.67', '3.0', '2.0', '4.0', '3.33', '4.0']]

def try_convert(val):
    try:
        float(val)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

# Get only values that can convert to float
result = [float(x) for values in grades for x in values if try_convert(x) == True]
# When can convert float(value) else None
result = [float(x) if try_convert(x) == True else None for values in grades for x in values ]
```